# One pass common statistics. Numerical stability for integers

Tags: algorithm, statistics, numerical-stability

I want to calculate `mean`,`std`, `skewness`, `kurtosis` and `covariance` using one pass algorithms. The simplest and fastest one approach I found was published by [Stuart McCrary from Berkeley Research Group](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=189069123081090098031090006084016103025072088045028034119097095076096066072091127027106016006035108029051125126102094071095023038010070008020107094092004099101023111020033003094089007074119011117092030018116118000067031066001090021000084025094021116031&EXT=pdf). For example for `std` one may use:

```
std = sqrt((sum(x^2)-N*mean(X)^2)/(N-1))
```

I read that this approach is not good enough, as it is numerically unstable. Unfortunately, I have no deep understanding of numerical stability, but as I understand it is some problem, which happens because of limited precision of floating points operations.

In my case, I will deal only with integer numbers from `10^1-10^6` range.

**May I use this approach in my case and do not take care about numerical stability?**

Comment: "While the textbook method can produce accurate results most of the time, a level of uncertainty remains that perhaps a
particular trial pushes into an area where the textbook method is inaccurate." The research itself does not give details of its limitations!

Comment: @BassemAkl Research not, but in plenty different places it is written, that equation above is the fastest and simplest, but suffers from numerical instability.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the numerical stability, you can normalize the data.
See: [Wikipedia: normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))

For example: you have a data set `X_1, ..., X_n`, with the mean `x_bar`, standard deviation `s`. Then normalizing the data by: `(X_i - x_bar) / s`